# RichFaces - Suggestion in ComboBox containing letter or combination

Tags: java, web-services, combobox, richfaces

What I have:

I created a ComboBox with the following values:
- Test
- Sample
- Example
- Lorem Ipsum

Typing a letter/combination of letter in the ComboBox will trigger the component to suggest a value that starts with the input text/combination.

Desired output:

Force the ComboBox to suggest value/s that contains the input. For example, typing 'ple' in the ComboBox will suggest the values Sample and Example.

I tried browsing [this example](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/suggestionBox.jsf?c=suggestionBox&tab=usage) as suggested by [Bozho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203907/bozho) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773432/how-to-change-the-suggestion-made-by-the-richfaces-combobox) but I didn't get anything.

My IDE is NetBeans 6.9.1, RichFaces version is 3.3.3 if you may ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ComboBox can't be customized that way, suggestionBox can, as is shown in the example.

```
<rich:suggestionbox suggestionAction="#{capitalsBean.autocomplete}" … >
```

so you change the method

```
public List<Capital> autocomplete(Object suggest) {
    String pref = (String)suggest;
    ArrayList<Capital> result = new ArrayList<Capital>();

    Iterator<Capital> iterator = getCapitals().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Capital elem = ((Capital) iterator.next());
        if ((elem.getName() != null && elem.getName().toLowerCase().indexOf(pref.toLowerCase()) == 0) || "".equals(pref))
        {
            result.add(elem);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

to check for substring instead

```
elem.getName().toLowerCase().indexOf(pref.toLowerCase()) != -1)
```